Help me identify this film - child paralysis
I'm in search of a film a saw when I was a kid. From what I remember the film may be about a child who is paralyzed.
I have in mind a scene where the parents(or doctors), in their despair are saying to the child (more times) something like this:

Tell your brain to tell your body to tell your hand to move its finger.

And the child moves one of his fingers and everybody is excited and happy because this was like a very big step towards his recovery.
It was a dramatic film and maybe inspired by a true story.

You saw the movie when you where a kid, how old are you? You should add a possible timeframe to you question.

I think it might be called Lorenzo's oil?

A boy develops a disease so rare that nobody is working on a cure, so his father decides to learn all about it and tackle the problem himself.

The part you mentioned was probably the very end of the movie.

Better to elaborate your answer, like why you consider it as match, movie synopsis, trailer etc.

That's it! Lorenzo's Oil is the film I am looking for. Thanks for your answer user28131. I should have added that is a film from the '90. I wasn't able to find it nowhere on google. Thanks a lot.

Hello @Andrei, would you please mark the question as corrected? So, no one else post anything. Or you need more information?
